# Fort Frame head tube cracked

Tags: frames

I have raced my Fort Bike for some time now. The head tube holding the forks has split /cracked open. What do I do now, who do I contact ?
Dennis

Comment: If it's under warranty contact the manufacturer's representative (who may or may not be the bike vendor).  If not, contact someone who sells new bikes.

Comment: You're going to need a different bike. Try your bike shop.

Comment: Noone else has said it, so the first thing you do is stop riding that bike.
Arrange an alternate bike if you need one.  Then go ahead with the warranty claim, or if its been misused and abused, then no warranty will cover that.   Don't let this put you off cycling.

Answer (score 2):

The only Fort frames I've seen have been their cyclocross bikes and all of those were aluminum. Assuming we're talking about the same Czech made Fort frames then your only option is a new frame. Aluminum is effectively not repairable the way titanium, steel or carbon are. Depending on the age of the frame you might be able to get it replaced by the importer under warranty assuming you're the original owner. Then again, an alloy frame designed for racing (and especially cyclocross racing) isn't expected to last forever. Head tubes do take a major beating, especially in cross. Between the bumps and braking forces it's not exactly uncommon to see cracked head tubes.

Answer (score 2):

Fort Frames had a two year warranty on original purchase when I was on the factory cross team. Not sure what their current terms are now but they are imported by Fulton Cycles in Fresno, Ca. 
Here's the link.
 http://www.fultoncycleworks.com/fort-bicycles/

Darren would be the guy to talk to there.

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles.  That is good relevant information in your answer.  I look forward to your future contributions as well.